# CountDownTimer Android to stop current activity and go to the next one

Tags: android, countdowntimer

i want to add some countdown timer to my activity, e.g. there will be a one minute timer and during that time a user is asked to memorize certain pictures. after one minute is passed (from that activity), a pop up message will show that the user has to go to the next screen. is there anyone who can help me out? thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code snippet:

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

 public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

 }

 public void onFinish() {



new AlertDialog.Builder(this)
    .setTitle("Navigate")
    .setMessage("Next Activity?")
    .setPositiveButton(android.R.string.yes, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // continue with delete

// start intent to next activity
        }
     })
    .setNegativeButton(android.R.string.no, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) { 
            // do nothing
        }
     })
    .setIcon(android.R.drawable.ic_dialog_alert)
     .show();


 }  
}.start();
```

Answer (score 2):

use timer method as follows,

```
Timer timer = new Timer();
timer.schedule(new TimerTask() {
public void run() {
//run your code here
}
},0,60*1000);
// here 60 seconds * 1000 milliseconds
// finally don't forget to cancel the timer
timer.cancel();
```

It makes your code run for 1 minute then it moves to next block there are other approaches available check the Android documentation

or you can make use of following code,

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long end = start + 60 * 1000;

while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end) {
// do your stuff here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is the exmaple

create a object of the class given below like this

```
final CounterClass timer = new CounterClass(180000,1000); // 1800000 and 1000 are in milli seconds
```

here 180000 is equal to 3 minutes

`180000/1000` = 180 seconds and 180/60 = 3 minutes

and 1000 in `CounterClass(180000,1000);` means interval between the next tick

**and for 1 Minute use 60000 instead of 1800000**

Start the timer

```
  timer.start();
```

end the timer

```
  timer.cancel();
```

here is the counter class

```
 public class CounterClass extends CountDownTimer {  
      public CounterClass(long millisInFuture, long countDownInterval) {  
           super(millisInFuture, countDownInterval);  
      }  
      @Override  // when timer is finished
     public void onFinish() {  
       System.out.println("Completed.");  

       // here start the new activity
     }  
      @Override  // on every tick of the timer
      public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {  
            long millis = millisUntilFinished;  
             String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis),  
                 TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millis)),  
                 TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millis) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millis)));  
             System.out.println(hms);  

      }  
 }
```

}

Answer (score 1):

try the timer thread and handle thread,

```
final Handler h = new Handler();
        final Runnable animateViewPager = new Runnable()
        {
            public void run() 
            {
                imageview.setBAckgroundresource(imageView[postion));
            }
        };

        Timer swipeTimer = new Timer();
        swipeTimer.schedule(new TimerTask() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                h.post(animateViewPager);
            }
        },1000,60*1000);
```